# POST to create a resource vs creating a new path element in REST

Tags: rest

I'm trying to define a REST API on top of a MongoDB database where I should be able to add collections and documents. Assume the following:

http://games.mydomain.com/database/characters/123

In MongoDB, I would have created the database, then the characters collection and finally the ironman document (which has an _id 123). The above record would have been created along these lines:

```
    POST /database/characters/ HTTP/1.1
    Host: games.mydomain.com 
    Content-Type: application/json
    { "_id" : 123, "name" : "ironman" }
```

If later I realize that I should break the characters in two subcollections (i.e. friends and foes), I would create them after characters (don't worry about the migration part):

```
    POST /database/characters/ HTTP/1.1
    Host: games.mydomain.com 
    Content-Type: application/json
    { "name" : "friends" }
```

and...:

```
    POST /database/characters/ HTTP/1.1
    Host: games.mydomain.com 
    Content-Type: application/json
    { "name" : "foes" }
```

And here lies the problem: both POSTs (collection and document) look the same! That is, how would a developer differentiate one from the other when looking at the API? In this particular case, wouldn't be "better" (or less ambiguous) to write the API like so?:

**To create a collection:**

```
    POST /{database}/createCollection
    Host: games.mydomain.com 
    {...}
```

**To create a document**

```
    POST /{database}/{collection}/
    Host: games.mydomain.com 
    {...}
```

-or-

```
    POST /{database}/{collection}/createDocument
    Host: games.mydomain.com 
    {...}
```

I know it's not REST-like, but the API has to create resources *and* intermediate paths (i.e. collections). Any idea how could I approach this problem?

Thanks in advance!

-- Tito

Comment: In a RESTful API, you would `PUT` to create new resources, not `POST`, no? This is probably a better topic for http://programmers.stackexchange.com than SO.